# Utilizing Generics in Go for Struct Pointers across Packages

Tags: go, generics, struct, interface

I have a program that is utilizing separate packages that call separate API services. I would like to write a `writeCsv` function that can be used as a `util` function regardless of which service the response comes from.

The general idea looks like this:

`serviceone` package:

```
package serviceone

import "json"

// Types from a package
type PayloadTypeOne struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Payload  JsonData`json:"data"`
}

type ResponseTypeOne struct {
    Data []PayloadTypeOne
    FileId string
}

type JsonData struct {
    // Various fields...
}
```

`servicetwo` package:

```
package servicetwo

import "json"

// Types from another package
type PayloadTypeTwo struct {
    Id      string `json:"id"`
    Payload JsonData`json:"data"`
}

type ResponseTypeTwo struct {
    Data []PayloadTypeTwo
    FileId string
}

type JsonData struct {
    // Various fields...
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/csv"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "my-module/serviceone"
    "my-module/servicetwo"
)

func main() {

    // Function that makes API call and returns JSON payloads from API
    // Implementation here isn't important for the purpose of question
    // It does return a pointer to each Response struct
    respTypeOne := serviceone.getResponseTypeOne()
    respTypeTwo := servicetwo.getResponseTypeTwo()
    

    dir := "my-module/data"
    _ := writeCsv(respTypeOne, dir)
    _ := writeCsv(respTypeTwo, dir)
    
}

// I desire a generic type that comprises both ResponseTypeOne and ResponseTypeTwo
// In the actual code, these are pointers to these structs
// I could probably refrain from making them pointers, but the structs can contain rather large payloads and I'd rather not continuously be copying the data around
type Response interface {
    *ResponseTypeOne | *ResponseTypeTwo
}

// A function that will perform the write to CSV using the same logic regardless of the Response structure.
// This function is basically writing the JSON string and some metadata (same for each ResponseType) to a CSV, so the logic is the same regardless of the Response JSON structure
func writeCsv(r Response, dir string) error {
    // Write the response to a CSV
    outPath := filePath.Join(dir, r.FileId+".csv")
    file, err := os.Create(outPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w.csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer w.Flush()
    header := []string{
        "id", // Always present
        "response",
    }
    if err := w.Write(header); err != nil {
         return err
    }

    // Loop through payload data and write as JSON string into CSV
    for _, res := range r.Data {
        loadString, err := json.Marshal(res.Payload)
        if err != nil {
             return err
        }
        
        // Write row
        row := []string{
            res.Id,
            string(loadString),
        } 
        if err := w.Write(row); err !+ nil {
            return err
        }
    }

}
```

I am doing something like the above using the Union types but am receiving an error:
`Cannot use type Response outside a type constraint: interface contains type constraints`

Basically, I am trying to understand how I can use different structs from packages in one central location for purpose of not duplicating `func` code.

Comment: It should be `func writeCsv[R Response](r R) error`. The `[R Response]` is called a _type parameter_. Type parameters are what allows you to write generic code. See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations

Comment: and if I want to access a field of the type, I am able to use ```r.Field1``` for instance (knowing that both unioned types have this ```Field1``` available? Is that the correct idea? Wow. this is awesome.

Comment: No, writing generic code that can access fields of _type arguments_ is currently not supported.

Comment: @mkopriva. I see. Hmm. that is unfortunate, because for this use case I wanted to be able to use a field that is guaranteed to be in each unioned type.

Comment: You might have an easier time using a classic interface - not type constraint and defining *methods* that are guaranteed to be in each underlying type

Comment: @erik258 What if they are just structs that do not have methods? Is there a way to define an interface of structs that share fields but don't share method signatures?

Comment: If you care enough you may want to track this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48522

Comment: You can do type assertions in `writeCsv` if you want, but that generally feels pretty inelegant.  In this particular case, you might want to consider delegating the implementation of `writeCsv` to the interface satisfiers so main can call `respTypeOne.writeCsv()`

Comment: @erik258 I see. So I still have to implement the ```writeCsv()``` method for each struct type even if they are identical methods when it comes to the logic? Darn. I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the logic in question in a new question and then ask for help deduplicating the two functions.  It's hard to suggest how to DRY out the two functions without seeing their logic

Comment: @erik258 Possibly. I'm not sure if I understand how to take that information and apply it successfully. Perhaps you can lend a hand with an answer to this question?

Comment: @erik258 I added the full ```writeCsv()``` logic to the question. As you can see, its using the same fields regardless of which ResponseType, and basically dumps the response data to a JSON string in the CSV. All of this functionality I have tested and works fine, its about trying to deduplicate this code in my codebase.

Comment: The more I think of this, the more I am convinced that we are talking of a XY problem. The response data types are identical except for the JSON data, and the way it is used is generic by default. So, what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Each service corresponds to entirely different sets of business logic for extracting from the APIs. They are completely different endpoints and they  require different params, etc. Thats why I have them broken out into separate packages. Are you suggesting to just create a single ResponseType? The issue is that the deserialization from the endpoint responses have a large amount of nested structs of various JSON which I reduce into a single struct like ```ResponseTypeOne``` but it may have various nested arrays/structs within it in reality.

Comment: @Coldchain9 But they produce the same output data, or ist the output data also tied to a entirely different use cases?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg The payloads themselves are entirely different JSON payloads, they have their own request/response logic, but at the end of the day, I am using the same ```writeCsv()``` logic to write them to individual files. That is why I'd like to have ```writeCsv()``` in its own utils location that can be used across the packages. Each PayloadType has a distinct nesting of structs that allow them to be unmarshaled in the request-making code.

Comment: @Coldchain9 In this case I personally think it is actually a rather bad idea to tie them together at all. Good code is simple. Go proverb: [Clear is better than clever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=14m35s) Simply create an interface PayloadDeserializer, have each of your payloads implement it and use it in your ` writeCsv` logic.